# Google Calendar APi - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to follow this tutorial

(http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html)

to implement Google Calender using JavaScipt but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: origin_mismatch

Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
response_type=token
access_type=online
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay874729177
origin=http://localhost
state=538915583
display=page
client_id=553681888475.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

My JS file:

```
var clientId = '553681888475.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyCh86BTa79UfqU3I_Y0jiWv2g3eXvMh6XY';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  checkAuth();
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  if (authResult) {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
   }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
        document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='content'>
      <h1>Events</h1>
      <ul id='events'></ul>
    </div>
    <a href='#' id='authorize-button' onclick='handleAuthClick();'>Login</a>

    <script src="../Controller/Cal.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The clientId you are using seems not a 'Client ID for web applications' which is required in this tutorial. Please confirm it.

Comment: Hi, i guess your method makeApiCall find all the envent in the calendar "primary". How can i do the same but only for the future events, or for event that occurs after a specific day ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to clear the contents in the "Authorized Redirect URIs" box. (When using JavaScript, do not specify any redirects.)

In the "Authorized JavaScript Origins" box, you have to enter the domain name of your site which in this case was just `localhost` as I am using XAMPP.

Comment: Do you have to put the port also? because I am running on localhost on different computers and the xampp isntallations are using different ports